# Best way to print debug statements in c++ with multiple nested functions

Tags: c++, debugging, io

Lets say we have 2 functions

```
int func_a()
{
  //do something simple

  if (debug_level > 1)
     cout << "Some debug message" << endl;
}

int func_b()
{
   //call func_a a couple of times
   for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
      func_a();
   }

   //do some more complex stuff

  if (debug_level > 0) {
    //only debug stuff related to this function, not stuff in func_a()
    cout << "Some debug message" << endl;
  }
}
```

func_b calls func_a but both functions are useful and can be independently called by the user.

If i use a simple debug_level like above, you can see that debug_level quickly increases as the layers of nesting (func_c calls func_b which calls func_a) increases.

In addition, it is not that intuitive to the user as to specify a high debug_level in function calls low in the "hierarchy" compared to a higher one.

How best to organize the debugging output? What is the best practice in large complex projects?

Comment: What does debugging level have to do with nesting of function calls?

Comment: Create a logging class.  Create a method that will increase the level and another to reduce the level.  Also create methods to log the file name, function name, line number and maybe time stamp.

Comment: @Barmar it does. For example, you call both func_a and func_b in main.cpp. There is no way (using simple debug_level) to print just the "top
 level" debug information without func_b printing all the debug from func_a subroutine call as well. Does that make sense?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews wouldn't a logging class using levels have the same problem as above?

Comment: You may have some Raii class to disable log/reduce log level that you could use in `func_b`.

Comment: For logging, best practice is to *not* use `cout`, `cerr`, or any form of redirected `stdout` or `stderr`. Doing that will tie your running process directly to its output file.  For a long-lived production process, that's a huge problem.  What will you do if your log file fills up your disk?  How will you rotate your log files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a very large project you typically need two settings in my opinion.

Debug level which is the verbosity of the logging. Such as "debug", "info", "warning", "error".

The other thing is location. You may need to set a filter to only receive logs from some modules. This can be realized in many ways. What we use at my company to encode the origin as strings. Pretty much like a url.

So a logs would look like:

```
/module-a/function-1/  DEBUG  "Enter"
/module-a/function-1/  INFO  "Value added"
/module-b/function-1/ WARNING "Called with value out of range. Using default."
```

etc etc.

Then, all this is pushed to a sort of database and we can easily ask queries by filtering on the location.

/ will match everything

/module-a matches everything logged from module a.

And so on.

In addition we can specify verbosity too.

This is quite flexible. Probably the hardest part in any logging system is to decide what to log, when to log it and at which level.

EDIT:
So to clarify if function a can be called from module b and c. Then pass in the module name in the function and let the function add its name to the "uri" and log with that. Then you can filter in the logs and find out which logs from the function was called from b and which ones where called from c.